# Custom Report Type with Multiple Parents?

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type, child-to-parent

Is there any way to build a custom report type that links to multiple parent object types? For example, my Opportunity links to a Contact and to an Account directly, but I can't figure out how to join them to my report unless I start with them as the root report object type, which I don't want (and one would preclude the other in that case anyway). Is there a way to do what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup this is pretty easy there is a "add fields related via lookup" link on the side of the report type layout editor:

[image: step 1]

Just click on that, select the parent object you want included and then the fields you want added.

[image: step 2]

[image: step 3]

Do this for each parent object you have.